# List to dictionary with keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list (myarray) that looks something like this,

```
[u 'item-01', 52, u 'item-02', 22, u 'item-03', 99, u 'item-04', 84]
```

I'm trying to convert this into a dictionary with keys and value.

I've tried looping but doesn't give me the expected results,

```
mydict = {}
for k,v in myarray:
mydict[k] = v
```

Comment: "key called name" and "value called number" sound fishy. A dictionary doesn't have any representation of what its keys and values are called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and extended slicing.

```
mydict = dict(zip(myarray[::2], myarray[1::2]))
```

The first extended slice makes a `list` of all even indices, the second of all odd, the `zip` pairs them up into `tuple`s, and the `dict` constructor can take an iterable of paired values and initialize using them as key/value pairs.

Note: Padraig's solution of using [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) will work faster (and handle non-sequence iterables), though it is somewhat less intuitive (and not quite as succinct as written). Of course, it can be one-lined at the expense of becoming even less intuitive by [using the behavior of `list` multiplication copying references](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) (see Note 2 on the table of sequence operations; an example of another use for it is found in the [`itertools` `grouper` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)):

```
mydict = dict(zip(*[iter(myarray)]*2))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can combine [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#iter) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip):

```
l = [u'item-01', 52, u'item-02', 22, u'item-03', 99, u'item-04', 84]

it = iter(l)

print(dict(zip(it, it)))
{u'item-04': 84, u'item-01': 52, u'item-03': 99, u'item-02': 22}
```

`zip(it, it)` creates pairs combining every two elements, calling dict on the result uses the first element of each tuple as the key and the second as the vale.

```
In [16]: it = iter(l)

In [17]: l = list(zip(it,it))

In [18]: l
Out[18]: [('item-01', 52), ('item-02', 22), ('item-03', 99), ('item-04', 84)]

In [19]: dict(l)
Out[19]: {'item-01': 52, 'item-02': 22, 'item-03': 99, 'item-04': 84}
```

Using a for loop like your own code:

```
it = iter(l)
d = {}
for k, v in it:
    d[k] = v
```